# OpenRecordSet too few parameters 4 / issues with QueryDefs

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Issue: I have a form (frm_input) where a user inputs a population range. Once the user enters the min and max of the range and clicks the 'ok' button, the values are input into a query (qryMasterQuery) and the query is run based on these inputs using a 'Between' statement referencing the fields in the form.

The ‘OK’ button also open another form ‘frm_output’. This form runs a function ‘percentile’ that calculates the percentiles of data in the query. The function is passed three parameters – the query name, the field within the query on which to calculate the percentile and the percentile to calculate.

The function and form run fine when I omit the "between" statements from the query. When I tried to tie it all together I received a 'too few parameters, 4' on my OpenRecordset() function. From what I've read I need to explicitly declare the DAO.Querydef object
and supply the parameters via the Querydef objects parameters collection.

Issue 1: When I include the statement:

```
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("qryMasterQuery")
```

I get a runtime 424 error message.

Much Bigger Issue 2:
I am still unclear on the sytax for supplying parameters via qdf.Paramaters. I don't want to declare everything in the query, only what's being passed to the function, i.e., the 'fldName'.

my code is below:

```
Public Function PercentileRst(RstName As String, fldName As String, PercentileValue As Double) As Double

    'This function will calculate the percentile of a recordset.

    Dim PercentileTemp As Double
    Dim dbs As DAO.database
    Dim RstOrig As DAO.Recordset
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Dim xVal As Double
    Dim iRec As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Set RstOrig = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("qryMasterFee", dbOpenDynaset)
    RstOrig.Sort = fldName
    Dim RstSorted As Recordset
    Set RstSorted = RstOrig.OpenRecordset()

    RstSorted.MoveLast
    RstSorted.MoveFirst
    xVal = ((RstSorted.RecordCount - 1) * PercentileValue) + 1
    'x now contains the record number we are looking for.
    'Note x may not be     whole number
    iRec = Int(xVal)
    xVal = xVal - iRec
    'i now contains first record to look at and
    'x contains diff to next record
    RstSorted.Move iRec - 1
    PercentileTemp = RstSorted(fldName)
    If xVal > 0 Then
        RstSorted.MoveNext
        PercentileTemp = ((RstSorted(fldName) - PercentileTemp) * xVal) + PercentileTemp
    End If
    RstSorted.Close
    RstOrig.Close
    Set RstSorted = Nothing
    Set RstOrig = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing
    PercentileRst = PercentileTemp
End Function
```

I am eternally greatful for any help as I am just about done banging me head on the wall.

Answer (score 0):

First a couple style tips. Dimension all your variables at the top of the function. And you can make your code text to look like code by surrounding by `backticks like so` or putting 4 spaces in front of each separate line.

```
Like so
```

You should not need to make a new sorted `Recordset`, as setting the `Sort` property will sort it.

Issue 1:
Don't forget to declare the `QueryDef` variable. Also, you missed the *s* in your `Database` variable *dbs*. Double-check *qryMasterQuery* is the right name.

```
Dim qdf as QueryDef
Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs("qryMasterQuery")
```

[See MSDN for more info.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff845129.aspx)

Issue 2:
You will need to supply the parameters for the query to work. That explains the 'Too few parameters' error. The method is as follows:

```
Dim qdf as QueryDef
Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs("qryMasterQuery")
qdf.Parameters("Prmtr1") = "blah" 'You can also use qdf.Parameters!Prmtr1 = "blah"
qdf.Parameters("Prmtr2") = 1234

set rstOrig = qdf.OpenRecordSet()
```

An alternative to supplying parameters is removing them from the query or creating a new query with the implied parameters already supplied.

[See the Parameters MSDN for more info.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff193967.aspx) Note the example is hard to follow and uses different methods.

Comment: thanks! going through and supplying the parameters solved the issue. the only other change I needed to make was to explicitly declare the parameters (rather than reference them from the form).

Comment: You can reference form objects, like textboxes, as parameters if the query is opened as a recordset on that form's module. Also please pick my answer if it answered your question. Thanks :)